# What is the difference between length and tape value

Tags: revit

I am unable to find that what is the difference between the value of the **tape** which has given on top and side value of **length** which is given in the **attributes**.
[image]

Comment: got solution for this?

Comment: No, that's why I have posted. @ArnoldBrown

Answer (score 0):

The `Length` displayed on the left, in the Properties box is the actual length of the Wall Location Line that was used to create the Wall. Now, what shows in that dimension (tape), in the View, can be affected by a number of different things like:

- Profile edits:

[image]

The above image has a tape that says 11'6" but the Length in the Properties says:

[image]

That's because I edited the Profile of the wall, which edits its physical appearance and not the underlying location line.

Also, that tape value can be affected by dimension rounding. Take for example a dimension that rounds to the nearest 6"

[image]

So the tape reads: 15'0" but the actual length value is:

[image]

So there might be a few more examples where the display value of the dimension is not the same as the actual length. We would need to see a sample Revit model to tell you exactly what the issue is in your case.

EDIT:

Another thing that just popped into my head is that I think when the wall joins with another wall, and they boolean each other out depending on end conditions, it might be that the location line is reporting a length larger than the actual physical form of the wall that your tape is recording.